# how to get the datalist option id and assign to the input data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to write this code in jQuery or JavaScript hoping that someone can help me reach this logic.

My goal is when I select the datalist option I want to get the attribute **ID** of the selected option and make it to the value of `data-set`.

```
<input type="text" id="city" data-set="" list="citylist"  name="city" required>
<datalist id="citylist">
    <option class="citydata" id="012801000">Adams</option>
    <option class="citydata" id="012802000">Bacarra</option>
    <option class="citydata" id="012803000">Badoc</option>
</datalist>
```

For example, I select the `Adams` with the attribute of **ID**
Then the output of the input now is:

```
<input type="text" id="city" data-set="012801000" value="Adams" list="citylist"  name="city" required>
```

Comment: Normally each `<option>` would have a `value` attribute instead of an `#id`.  Why do you need two values at a time rather than the typical need for a single value from each form control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the *input* event to the element using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) so that you can get and set the attribute property of the element.

You can try the following way:

```js
const cityInput = document.getElementById('city');
const cityListOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#citylist > .citydata');

//attach the event
cityInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.clear(); //clear the console
  //get the selected option
  const selectedOption = [...cityListOptions].find(option => option.value === cityInput.value);
  //check if selectedOption is truthy
  if (selectedOption) {
    //get and set the property
    cityInput.dataset.set = selectedOption.id;
    cityInput.setAttribute('value', selectedOption.value);
  }    
  console.log(document.getElementById('city')); //test
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="city" data-set="" list="citylist" name="city" required>
<datalist id="citylist">
  <option class="citydata" id="012801000">Adams</option>
  <option class="citydata" id="012802000">Bacarra</option>
  <option class="citydata" id="012803000">Badoc</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: thank you very much for explaining and effort